# Erdős' papers on Analytic Number Theőry

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

My adviser has often mentioned that Paul Erdős' works on Analytic Number Theory contain a myriad of techniques that any number theorist must know. What are some of his papers in Analytic Number Theory that one would recommend ?